# Source not found error

Tags: android, file

i am new android developer
when ever i run this code i get this error "Source not found." just when it reaches the 
url.openStream()
any idea how to fix this?

```
    try { 
        URL url = new URL("http://pollsdb.com/test.txt"); 
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream())); 
        String str; 
        while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) { 
        } 
        in.close(); 

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) { 
    } catch (IOException e) { 
    }
```

Comment: do you have internet permission inyour manifest? also, are you doing this on the main thread?

Comment: yes i am doing in in the main thread and yes i added the internet permission in the manifest

Comment: so should work now ........is it wroking?

Comment: no, it is not working !! still same error

Answer (score 0):

```
 <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

add that under your first manifest tag in your AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem too. But now, i have been solved this problem by reference http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html
about the thread use.

You need to create a worker thread to work for open the URL stream rather than using the main thread(UI thread).

Of course, you also need to add

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`
 in your AndroidManifest.xml