# Error: Source not found in Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, debugging

I am developing an android application which I have complied using API 14 initially, and now I am updating the API version to the latest one. when I debug the code then I am getting the error `"Source not found"`. I am using Eclipse classic and developing on windows 7. I have searched a lot but didn't find a good solution so that I can get rid of from this problem. please help me or guide me how I can download the correct source code using windows 7. I have gone through different links such as [android.opensourceror.org](http://android.opensourceror.org/2010/01/18/android-source/)
but it is out dated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Source not found error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11063564/source-not-found-error)

Answer (score 0):

You can attach android source code from Android SDK manager. Just check the option for `Source for Android SDK` option or using this plugin for Eclipse [adt-addons](http://code.google.com/p/adt-addons/)

[image]